# Web Page timed opener not working (Java)

Tags: java

I am writing a code that will open a web page at 8AM. I plan to initiate this code before I leave for school (at approximately 6:30 AM) and read the page that it opened when I return home (at approximately 3:30 PM) For this example of my code, I put in YouTube as to keep the integrity of the web page that I plan to open safe. However, I have been trying for hours and hours with no luck to get this code working. I do not have much knowledge of the Java language (which is a huge error on my part) and I really need this code up and running soon. Please help me!

EDIT: I'm not sure which part of the code is failing. When I run it in the Eclipse console, it displays no errors and just doesn't work. So to answer any of the questions like this, I'm not sure what's not working.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Browser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        while(true) {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask tt = new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //this is the method you should use, not the Date(), because it is depreciated.

                    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);//get the hour number of the day, from 0 to 23

                    if(hour == 8){
                        String url = "http://www.youtube.com";

                        if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
                            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                            try {
                                desktop.browse(new URI(url));
                            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                            try {
                                runtime.exec("xdg-open " + url);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Not getting your code to work is a bit vague, which part of it is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never schedule the TimerTask `tt`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if(hour == 8) {
                String url = "http://www.youtube.com";
                if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
                    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                    try {
                        desktop.browse(new URI(url));
                    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    try {
                        runtime.exec("xdg-open " + url);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(tt, 0, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This made my code work! But after I do this, I only want it to open one of the webpage. How would I stop it after one?

Comment: If you want to open the webpage just once exactly at 8:00 am, then you should check that the hour, minute, and second are what you want. Without knowing your use case, it's difficult to understand your requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use case".

Comment: I mean, why do you need to open a website at 8:00 am? This could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm using the data that I collect from my REAL webpage (which as I mentioned before I am keeping secret) for an experiment involving that particular site at a certain time of day (which is 8AM).

Comment: Alright, if it's exactly 8 am, then you could test `if(hour == 8 && minute == 0 && second == 0)`.

Comment: I would also define "minute" and "second" using the same method as "hour" correct?

Comment: Yes, you would do something similar.